# How to manage memory in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm optimizing my app with perf monitor in simulator.

I can see RAM usage in there.

Here's a question.

If there is a stack navigation with A, B. A is default screen.

when I'm in A screen, the RAM is 125 MB, and when I move to B screen. it goes to 280MB.

and then when I came back to A screen, it's still 260MB.

It's supposed to be 125MB. isn't it?

How can I solve this?

I guess I need to remove event listener but I did.

maybe it's not working?

Comment: Have you using console logs in your app ?

Answer (score 0):

the memory consumption also depends on the components used in the screen, if you have a lot of components on a screen, not only it will delay the navigation but also more memory consumption. In your case i guess components are not being properly unmounted when you navigate to B screen.

Comment: component should be unmounted not only event but also all of components?

Comment: yes, by default components are unmounted. But sometimes it does not happen.